# Html download ficheiro Excel

Tags: html, download

tenho aqui um problema em fazer o Download do excel. 
Em PDF tenho assim:

```
  <a href="RH/Exemplo.PDF">
```

tentei colocar da mesma forma em excel e nao funciona.

```
  <a href="RH/Exemplo.xlsx"><img src="images/excel.png" width="56" height="56" align="middle" ></a>
```

Resolvido :

Acrescentei

```
download="ficheiro.xlsx"
```

Comment: Que tipo de erro dá?

Comment: não faz o download . Diz que a pagina não está disponivel

Comment: Não será problema no caminho para o excel?

Comment: o caminho tenho a certeza que está correcto. O Excel está numa pasta

Comment: Pagina/RH/exemplo.xlsx e diz que nao existe. Mas so quero fazer o download

Answer (score 0):

1 - Verifique o nome do arquivo, a extensão do arquivo. Seria bom ser tudo minúsculo, sem acento e sem espaços.

2 - Verifique o local do arquivo. Seguindo as mesmas orientações acima. Letras minúsculas, sem acento e sem espaços.

3 - Além disso, pode-se usar o caminho absoluto do arquivo. Está fazendo isso num Localhost ? Pode-se colocar no `href` - http://localhost/seu_site/rh/exemplo.xls. Se não, coloque seu domínio.

Answer (score 0):

O seu original está no seguinte formato:

```
  <a href="RH/Exemplo.xlsx"><img src="images/excel.png" width="56" height="56" align="middle" ></a>
```

Altere para este:

```
<a href="RH/Exemplo.xlsx"><img src="images/excel.png" width="56" height="56" align="middle"></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

É preferível colocares o .xls assim é lido por todas as versões.

```
  <a href="RH/Exemplo.xls"><img src="images/excel.png" width="56" height="56" align="middle" ></a>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54258/discussion-on-answer-by-pedro-luzio-html-download-ficheiro-excel)